Application of a theorem of Shalom
A theorem by Y Shalom states the following:

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $N$ an abelian closed normal subgroup. Assume that the Dirac measure at the unit character $1_N$ of $N$ is the unique mean on the Borel subsets of $\hat N$ which is invariant under the action of $G$ on $\hat N$ dual to the conjugation action. Then the pair $(G, N)$ has Property $(T)$.

Now, it is claimed that if one can show that the Dirac measure at $0$ is the unique $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ - invariant mean on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, then $(SL(2,R) \rtimes R^2, R^2)$ has Property $(T)$. I want to understand how the semi-direct product arrives here. I understand that the dual of $R^2$ is $R^2$ but want to understand how $SL(2,R) \rtimes R^2$ comes by showing that the Dirac measure at $0$ is the unique $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ - invariant mean on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb R^2$.

I'm not sure I understand the question ("how ... comes" is vague) but: if $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, its Pontryagin dual is naturally isomorphic to the ordinary dual $V^$. Naturally says in particular that this is compatible with group actions. So if the group in consideration is $G\ltimes V$, then the question is whether Dirac at $0$ is the unique $G$-invariant mean on $V^$.

I don't quite understand what it is meant by "action of $G$ on $\hat N$ dual to the conjugation action". The natural action of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ induces the conjugation action of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ in the semidirect product but I don't understand what the statement in quotes above means.

If $A$ is a locally compact abelian group, the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ on $A$ induces an action of $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ on $\hat{A}$. Hence when you have a semidirect product $G\ltimes A$, you naturally get an action of $G$ on $\hat{A}$.
